# Need help understanding contents of a .htaccess file

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I'm working on a blog using Wordpress and I can't figure out what the .htaccess file it creates is doing.

Here is the contents of the file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /welg/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /welg/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Does anyone who understands this have the time to explain each line to me? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
# If the mod_rewrite.c module is available then do the following
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    # Enable the rewrite engine, which is used to rewrite the
    # path to something WordPress understands
    RewriteEngine On

    # Set the base to this path. In other words, assume that the
    # website is always at domain.com/welg/
    RewriteBase /welg/

    # If index.php is called then stop rewriting ([L] means Last)
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

    # If the path is NOT a valid file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    # ... and the path is NOT a valid folder
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    # ... then always load the index.php file (which will handle
    # loading the page, no matter what the path is)
    RewriteRule . /welg/index.php [L]

# Done
</IfModule>
```

---

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /welg/index.php [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /welg/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: If I have all files of wp in welg directory and I want url `http://domain.com` then what should be need changes in .htaccess

Comment: @Irfan See updated answer. I believe that would do it.

Comment: FANTASTIC - WP handles 404s with that conditional at the bottom. I prefer to attempt to help the visitor figure out where they went astray and to log the errors so the administrator and attend to them. The only time WP uses a 404 page is when the blog post being requested doesn't exist. I've tested a lot of things and that's the only 404 WP takes care of. I want to give the visitors more help. THANK YOU VERY MUCH!  AH - is there a way to put line breaks in comments like this one? I find big blocks of text a tad hard to read. White space has its place.

Comment: @SimonT I am pretty sure the htaccess file only supports single line comments (`# a comment`). New lines are not supported. Just use multiple single line comments instead.

Comment: Sorry, I did make my self clear - I want a way to put blank lines in comments to questions here at stackoverflow - line the comment I'm typing now.

Comment: Thanks again - now I can do some sensible 404 processing

Comment: @SimonT Ah, nope, no newlines in StackOverflow comments. You can do Shift+Enter, but the newline will be truncated.

Comment: @Sverri M. Olsen, ThankU :)